# Can I get my iPhone to AirPrint to my HP Officejet 6500 E709n

Tags: iphone, airprint

I have an HP Officejet 6500 E709n.  It is not the exact model that is listed as "AirPrint" compatible.  Is there a way to get it to work any way?

I would love to be able to print from my iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not quite AirPrint, but have you tried the official [HP ePrint Home & Biz](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hp-eprint-home-biz/id299531647?mt=8) application?

I have it installed on my iPhone and it picks up and prints to HP Photosmart C4500 really easily. Also, installing this application adds a "open with" option when you are viewing a compatible document (pdf/doc/etc) in the web browser / email application etc. That means you just click "open with" then select Hp ePrint and it opens the document straight into the app ready for printing. you even get a print preview as you would printing from your desktop.